# git status reports "No commits yet" on existing repository

Tags: git

I've had a Git repository to control my emacs init file for some time. Today, somehow, things got sideways. Even though there are plenty of commits, `git status` reports: "No commits yet" and offers to track a "new file" `init.el`. Which is not correct. Indeed, the tracked file is there intact, the `.git` folder is there too (presumably not intact), the objects are there, and the files I would expect to be there are there.

I have no idea what happened. My hunch would go to an unlucky file system error, which happened to get some critical information in this repo.

There is really no problem of data loss, for I recovered it from my backup (it was a local repository, so no clone back alternative, but the backup got the job done). But, from what I read of Git, this is not something I expected. I hoped things would be more robust.

So, I'd like to know two things. What could have gone wrong from Git's perspective? (some info on that below). And how would I go about to recover such a repository, had I not done my backup timely?

As to what changed in the repository, I can pin it down to a number of files:

[image]

This is a unison sync screenshot which goes from the (good) restored repository to a (bad) later version which was on my external HDD, so the "deleted" files are probably a commit which my backup missed. Either way, the good version and the corrupt ones differ only in those files, all the rest is identical.

More precisely, `diff -bur dot-emacs "dot-emacs (corrompido)"` gives me:

```
diff -bur dot-emacs "dot-emacs (corrompido)"
diff -bur dot-emacs/.git/COMMIT_EDITMSG "dot-emacs (corrompido)/.git/COMMIT_EDITMSG"
--- dot-emacs/.git/COMMIT_EDITMSG   2019-02-19 19:33:23.000000000 -0300
+++ "dot-emacs (corrompido)/.git/COMMIT_EDITMSG"    2019-02-21 18:52:34.761102130 -0300
@@ -1,10 +1,8 @@
-Add make4ht intermediary files, to be cleaned
+Add LaTeX-item-regexp to safe local variables

 # Please enter the commit message for your changes. Lines starting
 # with '#' will be ignored, and an empty message aborts the commit.
 #
-# Date:      Mon Feb 18 10:10:12 2019 -0300
-#
 # On branch master
 # Changes to be committed:
 #  modified:   init.el
Binary files dot-emacs/.git/index and dot-emacs (corrompido)/.git/index differ
diff -bur dot-emacs/.git/logs/HEAD "dot-emacs (corrompido)/.git/logs/HEAD"
--- dot-emacs/.git/logs/HEAD    2019-02-19 19:33:23.000000000 -0300
+++ "dot-emacs (corrompido)/.git/logs/HEAD" 2019-02-21 18:52:34.793102485 -0300
@@ -295,3 +295,4 @@
 0c7b8edcde713c9792fc287c955c749769b440d8 2c5486c5c5cc6c45c0876a80ac51244dcd4f7c09 gusbrs <19410606+gusbrs@users.noreply.github.com> 1550495412 -0300   commit: Add make4ht intermediary files, to be cleaned
 2c5486c5c5cc6c45c0876a80ac51244dcd4f7c09 4ef5ff4538822082e8dd65d9251379e9be964cfc gusbrs <19410606+gusbrs@users.noreply.github.com> 1550578780 -0300   commit (amend): Add make4ht intermediary files, to be cleaned
 4ef5ff4538822082e8dd65d9251379e9be964cfc 3fc15187e0a6d3a12580c990b08e62e77bd24db7 gusbrs <19410606+gusbrs@users.noreply.github.com> 1550578790 -0300   commit (amend): Add make4ht intermediary files, to be cleaned
+3fc15187e0a6d3a12580c990b08e62e77bd24db7 0adb9ad30843f0cc7c48423ed0097a67c95add78 gusbrs <19410606+gusbrs@users.noreply.github.com> 1550753569 -0300   commit: Add LaTeX-item-regexp to safe local variables
diff -bur dot-emacs/.git/logs/refs/heads/master "dot-emacs (corrompido)/.git/logs/refs/heads/master"
--- dot-emacs/.git/logs/refs/heads/master   2019-02-19 19:33:23.000000000 -0300
+++ "dot-emacs (corrompido)/.git/logs/refs/heads/master"    2019-02-21 18:52:34.797102530 -0300
@@ -275,3 +275,4 @@
 0c7b8edcde713c9792fc287c955c749769b440d8 2c5486c5c5cc6c45c0876a80ac51244dcd4f7c09 gusbrs <19410606+gusbrs@users.noreply.github.com> 1550495412 -0300   commit: Add make4ht intermediary files, to be cleaned
 2c5486c5c5cc6c45c0876a80ac51244dcd4f7c09 4ef5ff4538822082e8dd65d9251379e9be964cfc gusbrs <19410606+gusbrs@users.noreply.github.com> 1550578780 -0300   commit (amend): Add make4ht intermediary files, to be cleaned
 4ef5ff4538822082e8dd65d9251379e9be964cfc 3fc15187e0a6d3a12580c990b08e62e77bd24db7 gusbrs <19410606+gusbrs@users.noreply.github.com> 1550578790 -0300   commit (amend): Add make4ht intermediary files, to be cleaned
+3fc15187e0a6d3a12580c990b08e62e77bd24db7 0adb9ad30843f0cc7c48423ed0097a67c95add78 gusbrs <19410606+gusbrs@users.noreply.github.com> 1550753569 -0300   commit: Add LaTeX-item-regexp to safe local variables
Only in dot-emacs (corrompido)/.git/objects/0a: db9ad30843f0cc7c48423ed0097a67c95add78
Only in dot-emacs (corrompido)/.git/objects/43: b802457cc9ab2d15146fbaf5711e76d0b11f6f
Only in dot-emacs (corrompido)/.git/objects/56: 49d3b00a4c1721287df6de1b8bfde1cf909089
diff -bur dot-emacs/.git/refs/heads/master "dot-emacs (corrompido)/.git/refs/heads/master"
--- dot-emacs/.git/refs/heads/master    2019-02-19 19:33:23.000000000 -0300
+++ "dot-emacs (corrompido)/.git/refs/heads/master" 2019-02-21 18:52:34.801102573 -0300
@@ -1 +0,0 @@
-3fc15187e0a6d3a12580c990b08e62e77bd24db7
diff -bur dot-emacs/init.el "dot-emacs (corrompido)/init.el"
--- dot-emacs/init.el   2019-02-19 19:33:23.000000000 -0300
+++ "dot-emacs (corrompido)/init.el"    2019-02-21 18:52:34.813102706 -0300
@@ -105,6 +105,7 @@
 (add-to-list 'safe-local-variable-values '(outline-hide-sublevels 1) t); overview
 (add-to-list 'safe-local-variable-values '(eval outline-hide-body) t); contents
 (add-to-list 'safe-local-variable-values '(eval outline-show-all) t); showall
+(add-to-list 'safe-local-variable-values '(LaTeX-item-regexp . "\\(bib\\)?item\\b\\|texto\\b") t)

 ;; Don't ask for confirmation for "confusing" commands
 (put 'dired-find-alternate-file 'disabled nil)
```

I still have the corrupt version of the repository to play with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reproduce this symptom with `>.git/refs/heads/master`, then do e.g. `git status` to see what you saw before.

Fix it with

```
tail -1 .git/logs/refs/heads/master \
| cut -d' ' -f2 >.git/refs/heads/master
```

Something truncated that file, the one git uses to hold an active master-branch tip ref (inactive refs tend to eventually get packed into  `.git/packed-refs`).  It's hard to tell what did it, the most plausible typo I can imagine that would do it would be wanting to type `$project/.git/refs/heads/master` and somehow actually typing `$project>.git/refs/heads/master`.  Not very likely-looking, I know, but whatever went wrong you're not likely to find out, you could run with all the management/security audits turned on and then if this ever happens again hunt through the audit logs to find out exactly who touched what.  (Mainframes have a "system management facility" log that logs *all* dataset access, stuff like this is one of the reasons robot tape libraries exist).

Comment: Indeed! I can recreate the problem and fix it as you describe. Quite impressive that you could get that. How it came to be, I don't know. I'm using git through magit, so I don't even directly type the git commands. But considering the nature of the issue and the fact that I'm the only one using this repository, I should keep observant. Still, I am somewhat surprised by this sensitivity of git to it. Anyway, thank you very much!

Comment: A new root branch has no commit yet, you can create them with `git checkout --orphan newbranch` and get the same symptom so there's legit ways to get what you described, it's just unusual to see that on an active branch. Coulda been a reboot at a really bad time, where the metadata was logged but the data was still in cache, if you're running ext4 data=writeback with a long commit interval like I do you can get this, I just know when would be really good time to sync.

Comment: Perhaps. As a matter of fact, I get plenty of power outages/spikes around here. I just didn't expect one byte to make such a bite. After all, the logic of Git is sort of keeping basically everything, with hashes to ensure data integrity and so on. And, all of a sudden, I loose the "gatekeeper" pointer to my master and things become completely inaccessible. That's sort of a bummer... Even if it is my fault, which is a possibility we cannot exclude.

Comment: The filesystem _can_ protect against things like this, you can use  `data=journal` for ironclad guarantees, but that slows everything down. Even with, like, money on the line, the long-term cheaper and better way that doesn't hurt performance is to have backup power.  It's a tradeoff, the only question is whether recovery when shit goes south amortizes out cheaper than prophylactic measures slowing you down every step of the way.  "All good hurdlers fall".

Comment: Indeed, there is always a possibility things go wrong, and a price to reduce it's probability. Thank you very much for your comments and, once again, for helping me understand what went on.